# Différence sémantique entre complément du nom et adjectif

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, compléments

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence de sens entre l'utilisation du complément du nom et celle d'un adjectif?

Voici quelques exemples qui me mettent le doute:

- l'histoire africaine/l'histoire de l'Afrique,
- la grammaire latine/la grammaire du Latin,
- un jour d'exception/un jour exceptionnel.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a des différences d'usage qui font que les formes sont quelquefois légèrement différentes.

---

- l'histoire de l'Afrique → Tous les événements historiques qui concernent l'Afrique, un livre les relatant.
- l'histoire africaine → Peut parfois aussi désigner un récit qui se passe en Afrique ou qui à trait à l'Afrique.

---

- la grammaire du latin (sans majuscule)
- la grammaire latine

Les deux me semblent équivalents. On trouve des ouvrages avec l'un ou l'autre de ces titres.

---

- un jour d'exception
- un jour exceptionnel

La première forme est beaucoup plus rare. Elle pourrait éventuellement aussi vouloir dire *un jour où il y a une exception (à une règle)*